# How to make apex chart react pie bar thicker

Tags: reactjs, pie-chart, apexcharts, donut-chart

*How do i make the bar thicker?*

```
import React from "react";
import Chart from "react-apexcharts";

 const series = [44, 55, 41, 17, 15];
 const options = {
 chart: {
 type: "donut"
 }
 };

 export default function PieChart() {
 return (
  <div>
  <Chart options={options} series={series} type="donut" height={300} />
  </div>
 );
 }
```

*sandbox sample here https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-pateu-tv4t5q?file=/src/App.tsx *

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `plotOptions -> pie -> donut --> size` to increase or decrease the donut size. Increasing the donut size would decrease the bar width & vice versa. Updated [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-monad-2j080l?file=/src/App.tsx)

```
const options = {
  chart: {
    type: "donut"
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      donut: {
        size: "25%"
      }
    }
  }
};
```